# SQL Server Compact 4.0 request to crl.microsoft.com

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Why SQL Server Compact 4.0 sends a request to http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/MicCodSigPCA_08-31-2010.crl and http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/microsoftrootcert.crl when the program starts? And how is it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, disable CRL checking http://www.page-house.com/blog/2009/04/how-to-disable-crl-checking.html